# DAX formula to concatenate three columns

Tags: concatenation, ssas, dax

I am mew to DAX. How can I concatenate three different columns say First_Name, Middle_Name and Last_Name to a single column with a space in between using CONCATENATE function in DAX. 
At present I could concatenate only two columns.

**=CONCATENATE(FIRST_NAME],CONCATENATE(" ",[LAST_NAME]))**

If any other function is there please do let me know that also. 
My aim is to concatenate 1st Name, 2nd Name and 3rd Name into a single column in SSAS Tabular Model

Please help me. Thanks in  Advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the columns are already text, you can use th `&` operator, i. e. use

```
[FIRST_NAME] & " " & [LAST_NAME]
```

You can find the documentation of `concatenate` - including the fact that it only accepts two arguments - at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634811.aspx.

Comment: Thank You very much. The '&' served the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming back to this, particularly if you have more than two variables to concatenate, consider using [COMBINEVALUES()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/combinevalues-function-dax):

```
=COMBINEVALUES(<delimiter>, <expression>, <expression>[, <expression>]…)
```

For the posted question, this would look like:

```
=COMBINEVALUES(" ", [FIRST NAME], [LAST NAME])
```

And can be expanded to include additional values after `[LAST NAME]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested CONCATENATE functions with the `&` to append your spaces.  Following your example:

```
=CONCATENATE([FIRST NAME]&" ", CONCATENATE([MIDDLE NAME]&" ", [LAST NAME]))
```

Comment: CONCATENATE is not available in DAX

Comment: @Sam are you sure?  This function is available in DaxStudio (I'm using version 2.7.4) and the Microsoft reference for it is here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenate-function-dax